# How can I update a polymorphic many-to-many pivot record (using the exact pivot id) in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I want to access my polymorphic (many-to-many) relation in pivot level. Lets say I have:

```
- pages
  id - title
- articles
  id - title - body
- quotes
  id - title - body
- pageables
  id - order - pageable_type - pageable_id - page_id
```

Now as you can see I have pages that can have articles and quotes. So that I can call a page and its contents (articles and quotes) in an order. For example:

```
  page1
     article1
     quote3
  page2
     article2
     quote1
  page3
     article1
     quote1
     article1
```

Note that 'page3' has two 'article1'. A page can have multiple **same** articles or quotes. Actually that's why I need to update the **exact** pivot using it's **exact** row id. Yes I could use the sync() method but it would delete all duplicate records. Even if I would use syncWithoutDetaching() I wouldn't be able to update the exact pivot I want. On the other hand I tried the  updateExistingPivot() method but it doesn't update (the exact) pivot as well. For example:

```
\App\Article::find(1)->pages()->updateExistingPivot(3, ['page_id'=>1]);
```

Here the first parameter is assumed t o be the id of the page and not the id of the pivot row itself (normally the pivot table hasn't a id at all).

Is there any laravelish way to do that? (except using fluent query builder or not accepting duplicate records at the first place :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
public function pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Page')->withPivot('row_id', 'other_field_in_pivot_table_you_need');
}

\App\Article::find(1)
    ->pages()
    ->newPivotStatement()
    ->where('row_id', $your_row_id)
    ->update(['order' => 5]);
```

The `newPivotStatemant()` will be an object of `Query\Builder` so you won't have any Eloquent features in this case. That should be clear since you don't have an Eloquent model for your pivot table anyway.

Comment: Yepp, it seems that the newPivotStatement() method gives a pivot level access. Like you said $article->pages()->newPivotStatement()->where('id', $my_row_id_i_want_to_update)->update(['order' => $new_order, 'page_id'=>$new_page_id]) did the job.  By the way any idea what newExistingPivot( array $attributes = array()) attribute is and does?

Comment: @Skeletor: newExistingPivot() returns a model of class Pivot. You can fill that object with attributes.